# ¿Como obtener el valor de un input dentro de un td con un bucle each en jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿como haria para obtener el valor de cantidad?, en el alert no me muestra,eh intentando cambiandolo a input, pero no me funciona.

```html
 <head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<div >
  <table id="mitabla" border="1" class=" display table display table-striped">


  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Check</th>
  <th>Codigo</th>
  <th>Articulo</th>
  <th>Precio</th>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
  <th>Presentacion</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO001</td>
  <td>Mantequilla</td>
  <td>12.5</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En paquete</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO002</td>
  <td>Yogurt</td>
  <td>5.60</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO003</td>
  <td>Gaseosa</td>
  <td>3.50</td>
 <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO004</td>
  <td>Pul</td>
  <td>3.50</td>
 <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO005</td>
  <td>Jamonada</td>
  <td>2.10</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En paquete</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO003</td>
  <td>Gaseosa</td>
  <td>3.50</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO004</td>
  <td>Pul</td>
  <td>3.50</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
 </tbody>
  

  </table>
</div>

 <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
</body>
 
 <script>
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#enviar').on('click', function() {
    var filas = [];
 var tot=0;
    $('#mitabla tbody tr').each(function() {
      var codigo = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
      var articulo = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
      var precio = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
      var cantidad = $(this).find('input').eq(4).text();
      var presentacion = $(this).find('td').eq(5).text();
      var val = precio * cantidad;
   tot+=val;
      var fila = {
        codigo,
        articulo,
        precio,
        cantidad,
        presentacion
  
      };
      filas.push(fila);
  // var des = JSON.stringify(fila);
   //alert(des);
    });
 var desa =JSON.stringify(filas);
    alert(desa);
 alert(tot);
  });
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas buscando el input pero hay 2 inputs en la fila, el checkbox y el textbox.  Necesitas especificar el tipo de input que buscas con `input[type="number"]`.  Ademas, tienes un `tr` de mas en tu HTML.  Quedaria asi:

```html
<head>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

<div >
  <table id="mitabla" border="1" class=" display table display table-striped">


  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Check</th>
  <th>Codigo</th>
  <th>Articulo</th>
  <th>Precio</th>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
  <th>Presentacion</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO001</td>
  <td>Mantequilla</td>
  <td>12.5</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En paquete</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO002</td>
  <td>Yogurt</td>
  <td>5.60</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO003</td>
  <td>Gaseosa</td>
  <td>3.50</td>
 <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO004</td>
  <td>Pul</td>
  <td>3.50</td>
 <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO005</td>
  <td>Jamonada</td>
  <td>2.10</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En paquete</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO003</td>
  <td>Gaseosa</td>
  <td>3.50</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>PRO004</td>
  <td>Pul</td>
  <td>3.50</td>
  <td><input type="number" value="1" /></td>
  <td>En botella</td>
  </tr>
  
 </tbody>
  

  </table>
</div>

 <button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
</body>
 
 <script>
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#enviar').on('click', function() {
    var filas = [];
 var tot=0;
    $('#mitabla tbody tr').each(function() {
      var codigo = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text();
      var articulo = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
      var precio = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
      var cantidad = $(this).find('input[type="number"]').val();
      var presentacion = $(this).find('td').eq(5).text();
      var val = parseFloat(precio) * parseInt(cantidad);
   tot+=val;
      var fila = {
        codigo,
        articulo,
        precio,
        cantidad,
        presentacion
  
      };
      filas.push(fila);
  // var des = JSON.stringify(fila);
   //alert(des);
    });
 var desa =JSON.stringify(filas);
    alert(desa);
 alert(tot);
  });
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function agendar()
    {
        <!-- //Agregar los elementos -->
        $("#tablaPersonas tbody tr").each(function () {
            <!-- //OJOOOO---Indice de apararición según controles del mismo tipo -->
            var nombre = $(this).find('input').eq(0).val();
            console.log("Nombre: " + nombre);

            <!-- //OJOOOO---Indice de apararición según controles del mismo tipo -->
            var tipo = $(this).find('select').eq(0).val();
            console.log(tipo);

            <!-- //OJOOOO---Indice de apararición según controles del mismo tipo -->
            var sexo = $(this).find('select').eq(1).val();
            console.log(sexo);

            <!-- //OJOOOO---Indice de apararición según controles del mismo tipo -->
            var menorEdad = $(this).find('select').eq(2).val();
            console.log(menorEdad);

            <!-- //OJOOOO---Si hubira otro INPUT el Indice de apararición según controles seria 1 (UNO) por que el indice 0 (CERO) corresponde a nombre -->
            <!-- //var otroInput = $(this).find('input').eq(1).val();//Indice 1 -->
        });
    }
</script>

<table id="tablaPersonas" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Sexo</th>
            <th>Menor de edad</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="elementos">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtNombre0" maxlength="50" class="txtnombre form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboTipo0" class="form-control">
                            <option value="A">Actor</option>
                            <option value="A1">Demandado</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboSexo0" class="form-control">
                            <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                            <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                            <option value="X">Otro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboMenorEdad0" class="form-control">
                            <option value="S">Si</option>
                            <option value="N">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="borrar" value="Eliminar">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtNombre1" maxlength="50" class="txtnombre form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboTipo1" class="form-control">
                            <option value="A">Actor</option>
                            <option value="A1">Demandado</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboSexo1" class="form-control">
                            <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                            <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                            <option value="X">Otro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboMenorEdad1" class="form-control">
                            <option value="S">Si</option>
                            <option value="N">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="borrar" value="Eliminar">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>        
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtNombre2" maxlength="50" class="txtnombre form-control">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboTipo2" class="form-control">
                            <option value="A">Actor</option>
                            <option value="A1">Demandado</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboSexo2" class="form-control">
                            <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                            <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                            <option value="X">Otro</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cboMenorEdad2" class="form-control">
                            <option value="S">Si</option>
                            <option value="N">No</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="borrar" value="Eliminar">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo dejame ayudarte. Te hare un ejemplo para que entiendas mejor java script. Te estas adelantando mucho con jquery.

Primero que todo tu input no tiene un id o una clase que permita tomar su valor

luego puedes crear una variable (se puede hacer de 2 formas)

**

> la primera forma

**

```
var variable = document.getelementbyid("idimput").value
```

**

> la segunda forma con jquery

**

```
var variable = $("#idimput").val()
```

Luego muestras la variable en algun lugar de tu web

$("#div").val(variable)